# 16 bit MUL assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, 16-bit

On x86 16-bit assembly, if there is a `1` in `ax` and `0x10` (`16`) in `cl`, the following code doesn't put `0x1000` in `cl`:

```
mul cl  ; ax = 0x  10
mul cl  ; ax = 0x 100
mul cl  ; ax = 0x0000 (not 0x1000)
```

Why doesn't this code work as expected?

Answer (score 6):

Your source is 8 bits (`cl`) so the multiplication is performed over `al` only.

**Use `mul cx` instead.**

**Explanation:**
If `ax = 100h`, then `al = 00h`. Since the result of `mul cl` is placed in `ax`, what you do is basically to replace the content of `ax` with `00h*cl`, which is `00h`.

> Opcode MUL
>
> CPU: i8086+  Type of Instruction: User
>
> Affected FLags: CF, OF, AF, PF, SF, ZF
>
> Instruction: MUL src
>
> Note: Unsigned multiply of the accumulator by the source. **If "src" is 
>   a byte value, then AL is used as the other multiplicand and the result
>   is placed in AX.** If "src" is a word value, then AX is multiplied by 
>   "src" and DX:AX receives the result. If "src" is a double word value, 
>   then EAX is multiplied by "src" and EDX:EAX receives the result. The 
>   386+ uses an early out algorythm which makes multiplying any size
>   value  in EAX as fast in the 8 or 16 bit registers.
>
> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   Clocks (i486):  MUL reg8  13-18  MUL reg16    13-26  MUL reg32    13-42  MUL mem8 13-18  MUL mem16    13-26  MUL
>   mem32 13-42

Comment: @Milmar Ok. Beware of the content of `ch`. Best is to set `cx` to `10h` at the beginning, instead of setting `cl` to `10h`. Just in case.

Comment: this did just what i wanted thank you very much for this
i push cx anyway it was just unknown to me that using cl would mean that it would not go to the value i needed